# How to use psycopg2 properly in a prefork celery environment?

Tags: python, celery, psycopg2

#### Problem

I have a celery worker(prefork mode, 4 processes). In the async tasks of celery, I use `psycopg2` to operate the database (postgresql). Everytime I reboot the celery, it can complete a task, but when the second task come and manipulate the database, an error occurred: `InterfaceError: cursor already closed`

I find something in the [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#thread-safety), it says:

> connections shouldn’t be used by a forked processes, so when using a module such as multiprocessing or a forking web deploy method such as FastCGI make sure to create the connections after the fork.

Is this the reason for my error? If true, what is the right way to use the `psycopg2` lib in celery prefork mode?

(Maybe it is too expensive to make a database connection at the task start and close it at the end?)

Comment: How are you creating the db connection/cursor objects? Are you passing the same conn/cursor object to each of the workers or are they creating their own?

Comment: I create the db connection just after the creation of celery app, like this: `celery_app = Celery(...)`，`conn = psycopg2.connect(...)`, `cur = conn.cursor()`，and then use the the `cur` in the celery tasks

Comment: Pass `conn` object instead of cursor and make sure the celery workers are not closing the connection.